# Modeling curved table legs

Tags: modeling

can someone tell what would be the easiest way to model the curve on this table leg. I dont know how to get the corner as round as it is in the reference without mage the edge of the leg round too.

Probably its easy but i dont have that much experience.
Thank you!

[image: Table Reference]

I tried it with the spin tool. The edge looks ok now but I dont know how to get the vertices back to the table leg in a proper way. Is this the right way?

[image: table reference 2]

Answer (score 4):

You could build the outline, and then create the topology inside.

1. Start with straight edges, and then bevel the corner vertices
2. Add a slight inset (to keep space for beveling later)
3. Build the inner topo-flow so it doesn't get in the way of other corners

[image]

[image]

Comment: that look very nice, thank you!!! But i can not inset like you, when i hit I it deselects my vertices and nothing hapens, the same whe i try to use the inset options, it just deselects everything. How to you build the topo flow, with the knife tool or with loop cuts and merge by distance?

Comment: Hey :). You need to fill the shape before inset: *Vertex > New Face (F)*.